# Text wrapping to next line on screen resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a UI where I display an icon with some text(on the right side) in the same row on a tile. 
The problem here is that when I resize the screen, the text gets wrapped to the next line and even if I decrease text size, it still does not align next to the icon.
Can anyone help me out?
Here's a visual representation. This is when screen is full size:[image: Original]

And then this is what happens when it is resized:

[image: Resized]

How do I bring the text next to the icon like in the original size (full size)?

Here's the code for displaying the icon and text:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 resize" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Date of Birth">
      <i class="i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x icon-white" style="margin-top:17%;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h4 class="icon-white m-h4" id="dob">16-Jul-2014</h4>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change col-md to col-xs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 resize" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Date of Birth">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x icon-white" style="margin-top:17%;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <h4 class="icon-white m-h4" id="dob">16-Jul-2014</h4>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works!
but instead of replacing col-md, if col-sm and col-xs are added alongwith col-md, it yields a better result for all screen sizes :)

Answer (score 0):

change the cols to a single line, like col-md-12. Then apply the icon as a background.

Alternatively, use

`<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">`

and so on. 
Depending on your layout, you may need to adjust the cutting points, so the first approach is always better and desirable